# Android code showing abstract error

Tags: java, android

In addition to the already imported classes i also added these.
It shows an error stating that-->

```
anonymous com.example.abhaygoyal.retreivingandsavingdata.MainActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener
```

Code:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText

// ...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button registerbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);

    registerbutton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void OnClick(View v){
                    EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                    username.setText("Yo wassup");
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: `public void OnClick(View v)` should be `public void onClick(View v)`. Also, when overriding functions, you should add an @Override annotation to help notice these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your class might implement OnClickListener, so be sure to also have a method called onClick(View) in your class.